# How to bulk edit wordpress page/post urls?

Tags: php, database, wordpress

Recently I migrated some 1400 pages of static content to WordPress, but some of the URLs are messy and do not match the old site. Is there any way I can quickly edit many page URLs?

Only some URLs are messed up, so Database Query won't work in this case and In the WordPress codex, it is mentioned not to edit GUID column in the database.

Not sure if there is a plugin to do this. I am also using custom permalinks plugin for editing each page URL but it takes forever.

Thanks! :)

Comment: i think there is a plugin, its called `migratedb`

Comment: Instead of going through all the pages to update the URLs is it possible to edit it under a single page? 

The plugin you mentioned seems that works for a complete site migration, not to updated individual posts or page